# Javascript 2 functions for onClick only run last one

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a problem using AJAX. The 2 functions that are called via the onclick event, post each value toggle AJAX and back data in two divs. If only put one function in one onclick. it runs well. but put 2, **only run the last one** `ajax2('".$data."','".$num2."');`. Where is the problem?

```
echo "<a OnClick=\"ajax1('".$data."','".$num1."');ajax2('".$data."','".$num2."');\">" click </a>";
```

two js code, function is similar. just function number, processing page and ruturn div is not same.

function1

```
function ajax1(data,number) {
      HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      } 
      }
        var url = 'page1.php';
        var pmeters = "data=" + data + "&number=" + number;
        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);
        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) 
              {
               document.getElementById("return1").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;                 
              }
        }
   }
```

function2

```
function ajax2(data,number) {
      HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      } 
      }
        var url = 'page2.php';
        var pmeters = "data=" + data + "&number=" + number;
        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);
        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) 
              {
               document.getElementById("return2").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;                 
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: You really should refactor your code. Make **one** function that also accepts the target element ID and URL. And Ddon't `echo` HTML with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first line of both functions to `var HttPRequest = false;`. This makes the httprequest private to each function.